# Java Library in Android Project

Tags: java, android, ajax, rest

I want to make a java library (so I can compile it into a jar) that makes calls to a server. I then want to share this amongst android application projects so that I can access those simple calls.

Is using HTTPRequest the best way to do this?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Something about making web calls in the java way and sharing them in android apps seems odd to me. should this be an Android Library instead? (I believe those should only be used when resources are involved)

Sorry for the potentially simple question.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a common Java library that you can use with both android , and regular java projects.

Take a [look at OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) , it shows you how to achieve this. It is related to HTTP client, may be it already provides everything you need. You can extend it where needed.

For a simpler example ([~20 java classes](https://github.com/square/okio/tree/master/okio/src/main/java/okio)), take [look at Okio](https://github.com/square/okio) , the underlying io library used by OkHttp.